# Filtering using serializers.ModelSerializer

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

I would like to use a filter on class that is used to serialize a queryset. I constructed the following filter:

```
# define a filterset
class commentFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):       
    class Meta:
        model = comment
        fields = ['tag', 'title']
```

With a generic view, this works fine and I can filter this using: `?tag=23`

```
# generic view
class CommentsAll(generics.ListAPIView):
    model = comment
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
    filter_class = commentFilter
```

However for a non generic view, I can't get the filtering function to work (but the data is returned). The only difference I can see is that I am using `serializers.ModelSerializer`. Is there some way of making filtering work on a class of this type? My view is returning a queryset of the model data which is the same as the data used in the generic view.

```
# non generic
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):     
    count = serializers.Field(source='subcomments') 
    score = serializers.Field(source='score') 
    upvotes = serializers.Field(source='upvotes')    

    class Meta:     
        model = comment     
        fields = ('title', 'comment', 'tag', 'created', 'count', 'score', 'upvotes',)          

    filter_class = commentFilter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The generic views build in the behavior for filtering and pagination, since they can hook that behavior into the standard way they create and return querysets of data. If you're writing your own views you'll need to apply any filtering yourself.

Take a look at the implementation of 'GenericAPIView', and in particular the 'filter_queryset' method to get an idea how to go about that.

Comment: Thanks Tom (and thanks for a great API framework!). The only filter aspect that I notice on the `GenericAPIView` is this `filter_backends = api_settings.DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS` Do I just need to specify that in my class to ensure filtering in the same way?